# Is Machine learning a good approach for this geometric challenge?

Tags: machine-learning, math

For months I have been working on a conventional algorithm that positions circles with different sized radii and either positive or negative charge within an outer radius in such a way that the charge balances out as much as possible. You can think of it like differently charged magnets on an infinitely slippery oil film, arranging themselves until they reach a global minimum of forces.

[image: A very simple setup with reasonably good, but not perfect results]

So far, the results are not good and, especially for complex setups with many circuits, very poor. Also, the calculation takes a very long time.

Now I would like to understand if this is a good use case for a ML model:

I can create any number of learning data sets consisting of the following:

1. features: The xy coordinates, the radius and the charge (+/-) of the circles, where the number of circles can vary from 1 to 100.
2. target: for each setup a measure of the "homogeneity" of the charges.

With this, you could then possibly train an ML model, which you then only have to give the radii and charges of the circles, and it gives you back the ideal xy coordinates for each circle.

Would something like that be conceivable? Especially because the features are so "multi-dimensional"? And what would be a good start?

Comment: Any ideas if this would work?